# Cannot hibernate Windows after installing openSUSE 12.2

Tags: linux, opensuse, windows, hibernate

Originally my machine dual-booted Fedora 17 and Windows 7, and everything was fine. When I switched to openSUSE 12.2, it repartitioned my Linux partitions (e.g. I had a 1GB swap partition and it made it 2.5GB).

After the openSUSE install, Windows 7 hibernation stopped working. The hibernate option just takes me to the login page. Why did this happen? How can I fix it?